# How to do equivalent of a linear-gradient with opacity on a seamless background image in CSS

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

I want to do this essentially in CSS:

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1), rgba(255,0,0,0));
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
```

But instead of a *color*, I want to *gradient-fade-in-and-out* a background image, like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, url(/myimage.png) repeat, transparent);
```

How to accomplish this in CSS, or if it's not possible in CSS, in JS.

My image is a seamless texture, so maybe that might factor into the equation since it is repeated. I also want to set the `background-size` to different sizes to figure it out, so if you could specify that too that would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) to do this. You can specify the same properties as background thus you can easily define your gradient.

```css
.box {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/42/10/10);
  -webkit-mask-image:linear-gradient(to top, transparent, #fff, transparent);
  mask-image:linear-gradient(to top, transparent, #fff, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">hello</div>
```

Or you can simulate this using multiple background. You will not have transparency but you will have better support:

```css
.box {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top,#fff, transparent, #fff),
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/42/10/10);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">hello</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. For the second example, is there a way to say "make the fade-in/fade-out part of the gradient only 50px, then the rest is the texture in between"? Right now it just evenly blends which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Exacaticly!! Nice :)

Comment: It doesn't look like the second example works in safari.

Comment: @LancePollard check again, I was having a typo in my code. An empty `background:` at the start

Comment: I updated the question with what I'm seeing on safari. I did your background fix as well, wondering what is missing.

Comment: @LancePollard don't update the question to include the issue as it will be a bit strange. Do you have the same issue with your other question? If so I guess it deserve a new question. Probably you found a bug

Comment: Okay, I've made another question, thank you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246358/how-to-fix-linear-gradient-on-background-image-with-opacity-on-mobile-and-deskto

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url(your-image-url.jpg);
background-blend-mode: overlay;
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation how this solves the OP's problem. [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/3124333)