# How to apply equivalent of linear-gradient with opacity on edges of non-repeated image

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

Like [How to do equivalent of a linear-gradient with opacity on a seamless background image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245123/how-to-do-equivalent-of-a-linear-gradient-with-opacity-on-a-seamless-background/57245190?noredirect=1#comment100991903_57245190), but instead of a *seamless background image*, just a regular old image. How to do the same thing? Right now when I try it on a non-repeated background image the whole image is covered in the gradient.

```css
div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, transparent) top/5% 32px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent) bottom/5% 32px no-repeat,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/984/1000/1000) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

What I have there (above) is incorrect, the image is all covered under the gradient while I just want the edges (top and bottom) like 32px covered.

Comment: I would like for the image to fill the space, but have the edges gradient-fade-out to transparent, however it is possible in CSS (or JS if it's not possible in CSS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move `cover` to only the image or it will get apply to gradient and will override the `5% 32px`

```css
div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, transparent) top/100% 32px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent) bottom/100% 32px no-repeat,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/984/1000/1000) center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or specify 3 values on the `background-size`

```css
div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, transparent) top,
    linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent) bottom,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/984/1000/1000);
  background-size:100% 32px,100% 32px,cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```